# Conditional Selector in Ng-Options / Expression Based Ng-Options Selector / Recompiling Ng-Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am still very much in the learning process with Angular so I understand I may be approaching this whole thing wrong and would love to know the proper way if that is the case.

I have a set of cascading dropdowns - that is the 2nd dropdowns options displayed depends on what the user selected in the first drop down.

A simplified example:

HTML

```
            <select 
                    ng-model="1stDropDown"
                    ng-change="on1stDropDownChange()"
                    ng-options="1stListItem.name for 1stListItem in 1stList"></select>

                <select 
                        id="2ndDropDown"
                        ng-model="2ndDropDown"
                        ng-options="2ndListItem{{2ndListItemDescriptiveProperty}} for 2ndListItem in 2ndList"></select>
```

Angular

```
$scope.on1stDropDownChange = function() {
        var 1stListID = $scope.1stDropDown.id;
         switch (1stListID) {
                case 1:
                    $scope.2ndList= $scope.chocolateList;
                     $scope.2ndListItemDescriptiveProperty= ".chocolateName";
                     //NEED TO RECOMPILE ELEMENT HERE
                     break;
                case 2:
                    $scope.2ndList= $scope.computerList;
                    $scope.2ndListItemDescriptiveProperty= ".computerType";
                    //NEED TO RECOMPILE ELEMENT HERE
                    break;

            }
    }
```

After running the $scope.on1stDropDownChange function and inspecting the element I can see, for example `ng-options="2ndList.chocolateName ...."` which looks great but the ng-options directive did not reevaluate the drop down with this new change.

I want to have Angular reevaluate/recompile/reprocess (note sure the proper term) the ng-options of the select element after I change the list of options. I have tried

```
$compile($('#2ndDropDown'));
```

and also putting the change of the list in an $apply function. Both did not work.

Solutions that depend on database changes would not work in this case - I can not add new columns or rename "descriptive" columns to simplify allowing them to be the same. I also know that something to this tune can be done by creating different ng-hide/show scenarios - I have gone down this route and it becomes difficult to maintain. Any help/guidance is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out a way to do it 100% from the controller. I dropped the use of the expression inside the ng-options in the view and did it instead by changing the elements ng-option attribute and THEN recompiling (while specifying the scope which I was not doing) the element like so:

Angular:

```
$scope.on1stDropDownChange = function() {
        var 1stListID = $scope.1stDropDown.id;
        var element = angular.element($('#2ndDropDown'));
         switch (1stListID) {
                case 1:
                    $scope.2ndList= $scope.chocolateList;
                    element.attr('ng-options', '2ndListItem.chocolateName for 2ndListItem in 2ndList');
                    $compile(element)($scope);
                     break;
                case 2:
                    $scope.2ndList= $scope.computerList;
                    element.attr('ng-options', '2ndListItem.computerType for 2ndListItem in 2ndList');
                    $compile(element)($scope);
                    break;

            }
    }
```

Note: I technically could have just selected chocolateList/computerList inside of the .attr change but I left it like that make comparing the before and after quicker.